# Is it possible to generate token using ADAL.net library with out Azure secret Key through C#?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, adal

From Azure function i am calling an end point of another Azure function(http trigger) under the same Azure subscription(same Azure Tenant ID).

So now I have "TenantID" and "ClientID" of the destination Azure function with me , but i don't have Secret Key of it. Is it possible to generate token with out a Secret key ?

```
   string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, authorityUri, tenantId);

   AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

   ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, "");

   var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, credential);
```

PS : From angular we can access this same API using ADAL library with out Secret Key.

Comment: Did you set the App Service Authentication r your endpoint Azure function (http trigger) on portal?  Or you set authentication  logic in the function code?

Comment: Currently i am writing C# code in Azure function  to access another azure function and but  the other Azure function which i am calling is already set everything in portal

Comment: OK. Then may I know if you want to access the function (http trigger) with user privilege or just with application privilege?

Comment: Application privilege  , because all i have with me is tenant ID and Client ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a signed-in user, your application must authenticate with either a secret or a certificate.

If you have a user who can sign in, then you can use e.g. authorization code flow to acquire tokens that allow you to call your API on behalf of the user.

But ultimately, either your app or the user (or both) has to authenticate to get a token.

Comment: The situation is like this : There is a angular which calls back end Azure function .

Comment: @Aswajith you need to have a look at openid/oauth. if you dont understand the protocol it will be hard for you

Comment: I think the problem is not clear here . Angular side doing single sign on authentication and generating token using ADAL . That token is send to Azure function http request and at azure function i am authenticating it. Now the problem starts , now from Azure function i am calling another azure function API (they already shard me client ID, but they didn't send secret ID) , now my question is does it possible to call that api with out Secret key?

Comment: No, there is no authentication flow at that point that doesn't require a secret / certificate. Both client credentials and on behalf of require a secret.

Comment: Or you can use a Managed Identity? :)

Comment: @juunas Yeah that is what i want to confirm. So i cannot proceed at that point with out Secret Key :).